# Why the output of this python code is False?

Tags: python, reverse

Why does the following code:

```
a = [8, 0, 4, 6]

if a.reverse() == a[::-1]:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Outputs `False`?

Comment: Try `print(a.reverse())` then try `print(a[::-1])`

Comment: *Why the output of this python code is False?* - because `None != [6, 4, 0, 8]`... Some basic debug would have shown you that

Answer (score 1):

`a.reverse()` returns `None`.Its in place reverse.You can try `reversed(a)`

If its Python 3 , reversed will return generator, so you will again have to do `[i for i in reversed(a)]`

Answer (score 1):

Because `list.reverse` reverses the list in-place and returns `None`. What you are doing is this:

```
if None == a[::-1]: # which is obviously not True
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that when you do `if a.reverse() ...`, python executes `a.reverse()` and therefore modifies `a` accordingly. In other words:

```py
a = [8, 0, 4, 6]
print(f'before evaluation in if statement: {a}\n')
if a.reverse():
    print(True)
print(f'after evaluation in if statement: {a}')
```

Output:

```
before evaluation in if statement: [8, 0, 4, 6]

after evaluation in if statement: [6, 4, 0, 8]
```

---

An alternative way without modifying `a` would be:

```py
a = [8, 0, 4, 6]
if list(reversed(a)) == a[::-1]:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
print(f'after evaluation in if statement: {a}')
```

Output

```py
True
after evaluation in if statement: [8, 0, 4, 6]
```